# MySQL UPDATE multiple join not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying following update query with join, but it doesn't update matching row.

```
UPDATE table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.id=10
INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T3.category_id=T2.category_id
SET T1.value=T3.value
WHERE T1.id=T3.id
```

Is MySQL support update query with nested join?

Comment: It doesn't update matching row

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table1 T1
SET T1.value=T3.value
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.id=10
INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T3.category_id=T2.category_id
WHERE T1.id=T3.id
```

Comment: You should make a comment that the `SET` must follow the target table.

Comment: It throws syntax error like "1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN table2"

Comment: UPDATE T1
SET T1.value=T3.value
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.id=10
INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T3.category_id=T2.category_id
WHERE T1.id=T3.id

Comment: @loganphp Can you please provide me sqlfiddle, so that i can check the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am tempted to say your query should work. However, maybe MySQL does not like the fact the join condition on your second line has little to do with table1?

Does the following work?

```
UPDATE table1 T1
  INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T3.id = T1.id
  INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.category_id = T3.category_id
SET T1.value = T3.value
WHERE T2.id = 10
```

Comment: Sorry @Kévin, didn't see you answer

Answer (score 0):

It would be more ususal to see that query written this way...

```
UPDATE table1 T1
  JOIN table3 T3 
    ON t3.id = t1.id
  JOIN table2 T2 
    ON T2.category_id = T3.category_id
   SET T1.value = T3.value
 WHERE T2.id=10;
```